# powershell create folder in other userprofile with administrative privilege

Tags: powershell

i have a user with standard right, and i need to run a powershell script with admin right to do something, and finnaly create a folder and copy a single file in current logged userprofile.
How i can do this?

example:

C:\Users\USERNAME\FOO\FOO.TXT

i do this but, obviusly, create the folder in my admin profile

```
# DO SOMETHINGS BEFORE   

$directory = $env:USERPROFILE + 'FOO'

    if(!(Test-Path -Path $directory)){
    New-Item -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Name "FOO" -ItemType "directory"
}
Copy-Item "testo.txt" -Destination $directory


# Copy-Item "arDigiCore.ini" -Destination $arDigiSign
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

1 - i run my powershell script, logged like standard user (e.g. user1), like a admin (e.g. admin1).

2 - the script install a program, and before end, check and in case create a folder in the path C:\Users\users1\foo

NB: I do not know before the name of the user logged in to execute the program

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Please describe, step by step, what you want to do and what the result should be.

Comment: 1 - i run my powershell script, logged like standard user (e.g. user1), like a admin (e.g. admin1).
2 - the script install a program, and before end, check and in case create a folder in the path C:\Users\users1\foo

NB: I do not know before the name of the user logged in to execute the program

Comment: What are you doing in this script that requires Administrative rights? What do you want the effect of this script to be when run by an ordinary user? It is still not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i used the command: $userDir=$CurrentConsoleUserSession.UserName

Comment: So you are logged in remotely and you want to use information for the person who is logged in locally and create a folder in the local users profile path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query.exe` to pull the current users. Then filter the active user that isn't you.

```
$user = (((& query user) | ? {$_ -like "*active*" -and $_ -notlike "AdminUserName"}).trim()  -Replace '\s+',' ' -Split '\s')[0]
#Credit to Jaap Brasser https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea
```

then convert to a SID and match to the SID returned from Win32_UserProfile

```
$NTUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user)
$SID = ($NTUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).value
$directory = (gcim Win32_UserProfile | ? {$_.sid -eq $SID}).localpath

if(!(Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $directory FOO))){
    New-Item -Path $Directory -Name "FOO" -ItemType "directory"
}
Copy-Item "testo.txt" -Destination (Join-Path $directory FOO)
```